# How to create a favourite in bootstrapvue?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, bootstrap-vue

Guys I am using bootstapvue and I want to know how to create a favourite icon?
the documentation only have icons for rating.

However I have a list of reports and I want the user to click which is favourite, its like a check-box but maybe with a heart or a star?

Somehting like this==>
[image]

Answer (score -1):

BootstrapVue icon components are built from bootstrap-icons v1.2.2 source SVGs. Icons are opt-in, meaning that they explicitly need to be imported in order to be used. They are not installed by default. You do not need bootstrap-icons as a dependency.

Comment: hi Suman thanks for the response. I know the icons. But how do i go about create a favoutie option where you tick the button and it fill it? - Maybe this is more like Javascript?